# web API 2 image upload with Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I want to upload image with some properties value. I can do only upload image
Here is my Image Upload code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UploadImage")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ImageUpload()
    {
        // Check whether the POST operation is MultiPart?
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        // Prepare CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider in which our multipart form
        // data will be loaded.
        string fileSaveLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fileSaveLocation);
        List<string> files = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            // Read all contents of multipart message into CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider.
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
            {
                files.Add(Path.GetFileName(file.LocalFileName));
            }

            // Send OK Response along with saved file names to the client.
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, files);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }
```

CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider class:

```
// We implement MultipartFormDataStreamProvider to override the filename of File which
// will be stored on server, or else the default name will be of the format like Body-
// Part_{GUID}. In the following implementation we simply get the FileName from 
// ContentDisposition Header of the Request Body.
public class CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
{
    public CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path) : base(path) { }

    public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        return headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
    }

}
```

Function tested by postman [image]

I want to pass data which I can't achieve till now like as

```
{
    "name": "Mr.AAAA",
    "fatherName":"Mr.BBBB",
    "userProfileImage" : "image goes here"?
}
```

**How to achieve this?**

Comment: Look into custom HTTP headers

Answer (score 0):

I would perhaps consider doing this slightly different to achieve what you want. Look into base64 encoding your files prior to upload then it becomes much easier to deal with in JSON format by being just another block of text

Take a look at this [article](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/07/21/uploading-images-in-a-pure-json-api/amp/)